# How to reduce multiple branching conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, branch

I have found following piece of code:

```js
if ( selectedDataTypes && selectedDataTypes.length === 1 && selectedDataTypes[0].dataTypes.length === 1) {
  this.dropdownName = selectedDataTypes[0].dataTypes[0].name;
} else if ( selectedDataTypes && (selectedDataTypes.length > 1 || selectedDataTypes[0]?.dataTypes.length > 1)) {
  this.dropdownName = 'MULTIPLE SELECTION';
} else {
  this.dropdownName = 'DATA TYPES';
}
```

Would there be a way in javascript to simplify this branching?

Comment: By simplify what had you in mind? That's pretty simple already, and very readable.

Comment: What are the exact conditions for the 3rd (else) outcome? Perhaps if you coded that first, then, eg  selectedDataTypes must be set in the (current) first test, and you don't need the (current) second test. Perhaps that will be simpler, or perhaps it won't.